# Android ошибка с выполнением метода при отображение фрагмента TableLayout

Tags: java, android

Имеется метод, который отвечает за подгрузку данных с помощью Retrofit 2.

У фрагментов есть несколько состояний.

Мне нужно, чтобы при запуске фрагмента, загрузились данные сразу, без каких либо нажатий.

В каком состоянии нужно выполнить метод?

Пробовал в onCreate,onViewCreated, onCreateView, onAttach, но везде метод не выполнялся.

Я уже подумал, может метод неправильно работает, поэтому добавил в Log сообщение в 1 строчке метода, но и он не отображается в логе.
Что я делаю не так?

Код:

```
public class SmartphoneMainTab extends Fragment {
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_smartphone_main, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar)view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {

        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    public void LoadData(int id){
        Log.e("Start","start");
        progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);


        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(APIUrl.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

        Call<Smartphone> call = service.getSmartphone(id);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Smartphone>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Smartphone> call, Response<Smartphone> response) {
                Smartphone smartphone = response.body();
                Log.e("smartphone",smartphone.brand);
                if(smartphone.getBrand()!=null){
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),smartphone.brand,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Smartphone> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Ошибка",t.getMessage());
                progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Так а в каком методе тут loadData(int i) вызывается?

Comment: я во всех попробовал

Comment: это именно во фрагментах, относящихся к TabLayout. В остальных (например к Navigation Drawer Activity) все работает нормально

Comment: если метод написан верно, мб сам фрагмент не отображается? Проверьте вызывваются ли базовые обработчики onCreate,onViewCreated, onCreateView, onAttach. Мне кажется, что ошибка не в ретрофите, а в самом фрагменте, в его использовании

Comment: да, ошибка во фрагменте